# Process the form if the action reference to a php file in a deny from all directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the structure

- index.php
- app/processor.php
- app/.htaccess

in the index.php I have this form

```
<form method='post' action='/app/processor.php'>
    <input type='text' name='foo' value=''/>
    <input type='submit' value='bar'/>
</form>
```

The file which will process the form is located inside the app folder. The processor.php has the code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['foo'])){
        echo "foo is set";
    }
?>
```

And inside the app folder, I created a .htaccess to deny direct access of the files inside of it.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

My problem now is that I can't process the form due to the .htaccess file. The server returns error 403 because of that restriction in the app folder. Is there anyway I can process the form by still using the processor.php? Or should I remove/modify the .htaccess? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the `Order deny,allow` you can always add a section like:

```
<Files processor.php>
Allow from all
</Files>
```

And it should allow that specific file to be read, while everything else remains forbidden.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to still forbid access to processor.php but I guess that's not possible. Thank you for this!

Comment: I believe you have to design the application differently to accomplish that, you can't forbid access to a file that is supposed to be called by a user visiting your site.

Just make sure you write code where it doesn't matter if the users access the files directly without the arguments you intend, its the best course of security.

Answer (score 0):

Absent modification of the .htaccess file, there is no way to execute the code in your /app/processor.php.